# Fetching data from json file in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am working on protractor testing framework to test the Angular Js application.

I am stuck in a scenario where I want to fetch the data 
(eg: Test URL,Username,Password)from external file say Json File.

I have created one json file for this and written code to read the data from this json file but I am getting the error 
as:

```
DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[11:03:10] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:03:10] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[11:03:12] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.212.134.201:59697/wd/hub
[11:03:15] E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'E:LAM WAH EE_Testing EnviornmentDetailed_Sheet - Copy.geojson'
```

where `Detailed_Sheet - Copy.geojson` is the file where I have given the url name and username and password.

Please anyone having idea about this help me so that I will get to know where is my mistake.

Comment: Use `/` instead of `\` for your path

Comment: okay. I have also changed my code:The new code is: var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('Detailed_Sheet - Copy.geojson', 'utf8', function (err, data) 
{
  if (err) throw err;
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log("--------------Books Information --------");
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; ++i) {
    console.log("Test URL"+jsonData[i].Test_URL);
    console.log("User Name"+jsonData[i].User_Name);
    console.log("Password"+jsonData[i].Password);
    }
});
When I am running this I am getting the error: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0

Comment: Now your Json is malformatted. It can't parse it.

Comment: Is the above code wrong? Please let me know the new code so that it can work properly. My json code from where I want to fetch the data is: module.exports{
[
        {
          "Test_URL": "http://......com",
          "User_Name": "azizi@hlwe.com",
          "Password": "abcd@1234"
        },
       {
          "Test_URL": "http://.....com",
          "User_Name": "barakathk@hlwe.com",
          "Password": "abcd@1234"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: `module.exports{}` cannot be in a json file. `Json` means plain data. No `module.exports` needed. Remove that part or rename the file to be a `.js` file

Comment: Hello  Ernst, Thanks for the explanation. My code is working fine. I mean I am able to print the data on the command prompt. But I have my other code where I want to pass the values from the json file so that it can take the data from json and perform automatic function. My code is :

Comment: describe('Opne the clinicare website by logging into the site', function()
{
it ('Should Add a text in username and password fields and hit login button',function()
{
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
browser.get ('http://172.16.99.47:3001');

//Perform Login:UserName
element(by.model('accessCode')).sendKeys('azizi@hlwe.com');

//Perform Login:Password
element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('abcd@1234');

//Perform Login:LoginButton
element(by.css('.btn.btn-primary.pull-right')).click();
 Here I am using sendkeys but instead of that I want that i should take the value

Answer (score 1):

Please see below example, the example assume we have two files and they are in same folder:

1) login.auth.json,  its content as below:

```
{
    "loginurl": "http://172.16.99.47:3001",
    "username": "azizi@hlwe.com",
    "password": "abcd@1234"
}
```

Note: For json file, you no need to use module.exports or exports.xxx to export the json data,  you only need to write a valid json data in json file and use require() to import, then you will get the json data.

2) test.js, its content as below:

```
var auth = require('./login.auth.json');

describe('Opne the clinicare website by logging into the site', function() {
    it('Should Add a text in username and password fields and hit login button', function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

        browser.get(auth.loginurl); 

        //Perform Login:UserName 
        element(by.model('accessCode')).sendKeys(auth.username); 

        //Perform Login:Password 
        element(by.model('password')).sendKeys(auth.password); 

        //Perform Login:LoginButton 
        element(by.css('.btn.btn-primary.pull-right')).click(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello Yong,I am trying to execute the code but its throwing an error:      Failures:
1) Open the clinicare website by logging into the site Should Add a text in username and password fields and hit login button
  Message:
    Failed: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined.. Its not able to take the url from json file. Please let me know what is wrong in the code.

Comment: I made a mistake in json file, should use double quote not single quote, I had update the login.auth.json above.  Now it should work